# Как код на в софте сделать закрытым

Tags: c#, windows, обфускация

Как можно сделать код закрытым ? Ну чтобы его нельзя было посмотреть, c# - через рефлектор 8.x, 9 ....

Comment: Не писать на C#, очевидно же.

Comment: 1. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/465167/178988 2. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/426010/178988 3. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/609950/178988 4. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/624921/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy чем дубликатить?)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, звать обладателя золотой метки, чтоб он задубликатил сразу всем :)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский отдубликатил. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь протектором и\или обфускатором кода.
Есть платные и бесплатные варианты.